# Using the Identity Theorem to prove $\sin^2 z+ \cos^2 z =1$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have a question. Using Identity theorem, we can give proof of the standard trigonometric identities; in particular, $\sin^2 z+ \cos^2 z =1$.

My approach: Let $f(z) = \sin^2 z+ \cos^2 z -1$, so $f$ is an entire function. We know that $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x -1 =0$ for every real number. Let $x_0$ be a real number. Then any neighborhood of $x_0$ contains a point other that $x_0$ for which $\sin^2 x+ \cos^2 x -1 =0$. So, $x_0$ is a limit point of zero set, $Z(f)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. So, by the identity theorem $f=0$ throughout $\mathbb{C}$. So  $\sin^2 z+ \cos^2 z =1$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct and your argument is better than solutions below.

Comment: Yes; you could also differentiate and see the derivative vanishes everywhere, and note that $\sin^2(0) + \cos^2(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 4):

This proof is correct.  You can also use power series and show that each coefficient is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The identity theorem is not really necessary for this:

Let

$f(z) = \cos^2 z + \sin^2 z; \tag 1$

since $\cos z$ and $\sin z$ are holomorphic, indeed entire; and so thus is $f(z)$; furthermore

$\sin 0 = 0, \; \cos 0 = 1; \tag 2$

it now follows that

$f'(z) = 2(\cos z)(\sin z) - 2(\cos z)(\sin z) = 0.  \tag 3$

We now have

$\displaystyle \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f'(w)dw = f(z_2) - f(z_1), \; \tag 4$

and this in accord with (3),

$f(z_2) = f(z_1), \; \forall z_1, z_2 \in \Bbb C; \tag 5$

so finally we may affirm

$f(z) = 1, \forall z \in \Bbb Z, \tag 6$

that is,

$\cos^2 z + \sin^2 z = 1; \tag 7$